# Click on html element (by class) using WebBrowser c#

Tags: c#, click, browser, invoke

My code is:

```
 WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
            browser.Navigate("http://myurl");
            var links = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
            foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
            {
                if (link.GetAttribute("class") == "expand-chain no-tracks")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Click here");
                    link.InvokeMember("click");
                }
            }
```

And i need to get all html elements with "expand-chain no-tracks" class and after i need to click on it.

My problem is that i always get a NullReferenceException for reason "object reference not set to an istance of an object".

Html code is:

```
<a class="expand-chain no-tracks" data-chain-id="ZYZ" href="#" style="display: none;">
<span>
Some text
</span>
</a>
```

Please help me!
Thanks

**EDIT**
I tried also with this code but it never execute browser_DocumentCompleted function

```
 public void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
            var links = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

                foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
                {
                    if (link.GetAttribute("class") == "expand-chain no-tracks")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Here");
                        link.InvokeMember("click");
                    }
                }
        }

        public void cazz()
        {
            WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
            browser.Navigate("http://myurl");
            browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted);
        }
```

Comment: what is the element without a reference? links == null?

Comment: yes, links is null. and i'm sure page is full downloaded because when i try to get it with WebClient i can get it fully

Comment: mhh strange indeed. "WebBrowser.Document" is also null?

Comment: yes, WebBrowser.Document is null, and it never download page! allownavigate is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link, may help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET
I had the same problem but I'm using a ASP.NET application.

EDIT: The Atribute "class" is special. Try "className" instead.

Comment: Rolled back to the original author's version, because the link itself is so much of the answer that being able to readily see it's destination (vs having that hidden) is an important part of reading the answer.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't realize that. :(

Comment: `The Atribute "class" is special. Try "className" instead.` is very useful to me.. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add a condition checker when "browser" is not null before proceeding?. I think the event will be back later and your "browser" will be completely initialized.

```
        public void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;

            if(browser.Document != null)
            {
                var links = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

                foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
                {
                    if (link.GetAttribute("class") == "expand-chain no-tracks")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Here");
                        link.InvokeMember("click");
                    }
                }
             }
        }
```

Comment: i've added if (browser.Document != null) as you suggested but it never execute browser_DocumentCompleted function. it sounds like it never become DocumentCompleted true.

Comment: browser values during execution are: -  browser {System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser} System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
+  base {System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser} System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase {System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser}
  AllowNavigation true bool
  AllowWebBrowserDrop true bool
  CanGoBack false bool
  CanGoForward false bool
+  Document null System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument
+  DocumentStream null System.IO.Stream
  DocumentText "" string
  DocumentTitle "" string
  DocumentType "" string
  EncryptionLevel Unknown

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserEncryptionLevel
  Focused false bool
  IsBusy false bool
  IsOffline false bool
  IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled true bool
  ObjectForScripting null object
+  Padding {Left=0,Top=0,Right=0,Bottom=0} System.Windows.Forms.Padding
  ReadyState Uninitialized System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState
  ScriptErrorsSuppressed false bool
  ScrollBarsEnabled true bool
  StatusText "" string
+  Url null System.Uri
+  Version {8.0.7600.17051} System.Version
  WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled true bool
+  Static members  
+  Non-Public members

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'll watch this with my colleague. If I find a solution to your problem I post back my answer.